# How do I store first control in flowLayoutPanel c#?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am using windows forms.

I have `flowLayoutPanel` and I programmatically add some `buttons` to it .
What I am trying to do is: I want to save the first `button` located in the `flowLayoutPanel` into `ButtonToSave` object.

```
   flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection= FlowDirection.LeftToRight

   private void AddButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Button btn = new Button();                       

       flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
    }


 private void StoreTheFirstButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

          Button ButtonToSave = new Button(); 
          ButtonToSave = "First button in flowLayoutPanel1"
    }
```

Anyone knows how to save the first button located in `flowLayoutPanel1` into `ButtonToSave` when `StoreTheFirstButton` event is raised?

Thank you

Comment: It is not obvious why it has to be a variable.  Especially not a local variable.   Just find it back whenever you need it with `flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @Hans Passant. your answer is very correct and it worked as I wanted, please make it as an answer. thank you

Comment: Please use it to complete the Q+A you started, just flag my comment as Obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below.  You may want to look at my response at following posting ([How to (create and) add components to a Table Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678505/how-to-create-and-add-components-to-a-table-layout)) :

```css
        private void AddButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(StoreTheFirstButton_Click);

            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
        }


        private void StoreTheFirstButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;

            Button ButtonToSave = button;
            //ButtonToSave = "First button in flowLayoutPanel1";
        }
```